# Optimize xgboost for low false positive

Tags: python, xgboost

In xgboost, if you are building a classifier is it possible to specify an objective function to maximize the true positive rate when the false positive rate is 0.01 (1 in 100)?

Reading http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html I can't work out how to specify an objective function that meets this criterion.